# EDIT: Having Trouble with Static Variables

Tags: java, user-interface, static

I am writing a program that is supposed to take the input from two text fields, length and width. It is then supposed to calculate the cost based on the area and type of flooring selected. However, all of the static variables are not being used or updated by my program when I run it. Even when I click my Clear button, all of the fields will clear except ones that are declared static. Could someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong? If I try to remove the static, other classes aren't able to access it.

EDIT: I was able to remove the static declarations so that nothing in this class (Cost) is static. However, I have another class (OrderSummary) that needs to access the getFloorArea(), etc. methods from Cost. It also accesses methods getFirstName(), getLastName, etc. from another class (CustomerInfo). I did some reading and found out that I need to instantiate these classes so that OrderSummary can invoke these methods, I'm just confused as to where to instantiate these classes. In my Main? Or the class that I create the GUI in? I just need all of my information entered in the GUI to displayed in OrderSummary but I can't seem to figure out how to implement it.

I know I'm bad at this but I'm really trying to learn.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import helpers.*;

public class Cost extends JPanel {

static JRadioButton carpet;
static JRadioButton wood;
JButton btnClear;
JButton btnSubmit;
static JTextField enterLength;
static JTextField enterWidth;
JButton btnArea;
JButton btnCost;
JTextField txtArea;
JTextField txtCost;
JLabel length;
JLabel width;

static double woodCost = 20.00;
static double carpetCost = 10.00;
static double floorCost = 0.00;
static double floorLength = 0.00;
static double floorWidth = 0.00;
static double floorArea = 0.00;
static double totalCost = 0.00;

public Cost() {
    createPanel();
}

private void createPanel() {
    super.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints bag = new GridBagConstraints();

    bag.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    bag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    bag.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);

    ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();

    bag.gridx = 0;
    bag.gridy = 0;
    carpet = new JRadioButton("Carpet");
    this.add(carpet, bag);
    bg.add(carpet);

    bag.gridx = 1;
    bag.gridy = 0;
    wood = new JRadioButton("Wood");
    this.add(wood, bag);
    bg.add(wood);

    bag.gridx = 1;
    bag.gridy = 1;
    enterLength = new JTextField("0");
    this.add(enterLength, bag);

    bag.gridx = 0;
    bag.gridy = 1;
    length = new JLabel("Length");
    length.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
    length.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    this.add(length, bag);

    bag.gridx = 3;
    bag.gridy = 1;
    btnArea = new JButton("Area");
    btnArea.addActionListener(new AreaHandler());
    this.add(btnArea, bag);

    bag.gridx = 4;
    bag.gridy = 1;
    txtArea = new JTextField();
    txtArea.setColumns(10);
    this.add(txtArea, bag);

    bag.gridx = 1;
    bag.gridy = 2;
    enterWidth = new JTextField("0");
    this.add(enterWidth, bag);

    bag.gridx = 0;
    bag.gridy = 2;
    width = new JLabel("Width");
    this.add(width, bag);

    bag.gridx = 3;
    bag.gridy = 2;
    btnCost = new JButton("Cost");
    btnCost.addActionListener(new CostHandler());
    this.add(btnCost, bag);

    bag.gridx = 4;
    bag.gridy = 2;
    txtCost = new JTextField();
    this.add(txtCost, bag);

    bag.gridx = 4;
    bag.gridy = 4;
    btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit Order");
    btnSubmit.addActionListener(new SubmitHandler());
    this.add(btnSubmit, bag);

    bag.gridx = 4;
    bag.gridy = 5;
    btnClear = new JButton("Clear");
    btnClear.addActionListener(new ClearHandler());
    this.add(btnClear, bag);                
}

public static double getFlooringCost() {

    if (carpet.isSelected())
        floorCost = carpetCost;
    if (wood.isSelected())
        floorCost = woodCost;

    return floorCost;
}

public static double getFloorArea() {

    floorLength = Double.parseDouble(enterLength.getText());
    floorWidth = Double.parseDouble(enterWidth.getText());

    floorArea = floorLength * floorWidth;

    return floorArea;
}

public static double getTotalCost() {

    totalCost = floorCost * floorArea;

    return totalCost;
}

public void setFloorArea(double floorArea) {
    if (floorArea >= 0) {
        Cost.floorArea = floorArea;
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Length or Width must be greater than 0.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}

public void setTotalCost(double totalCost) {
    Cost.totalCost = totalCost;
}

private class AreaHandler implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        txtArea.setText(String.valueOf(getFloorArea()));
    }
}

private class CostHandler implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        txtCost.setText(OutputHelpers.formattedCurrency(getTotalCost()));
    }
}

private class ClearHandler implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        enterLength.setText("");
        enterWidth.setText("");
        txtArea.setText("");
        txtCost.setText("");
    }
}

private class SubmitHandler implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        setFloorArea(getFloorArea());
        setTotalCost(getTotalCost());

        enterLength.setText("");
        enterWidth.setText("");
        txtArea.setText("");
        txtCost.setText("");
    }
}

//class OrderSummary
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import helpers.*;

public class OrderSummary extends JPanel {

JTextArea orderSummary;

public OrderSummary() {
    createPanel();
}

private void createPanel() {
    super.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints bag = new GridBagConstraints();

    bag.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    bag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    bag.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);

    bag.gridx = 0;
    bag.gridy = 0;
    orderSummary = new JTextArea(5, 20);
    orderSummary.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
    orderSummary.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    this.add(orderSummary, bag);

    //this is where I need to get data from classes Cost and CustomerInfo
    orderSummary.setText("Customer Name: " + aCustomerInfo.getFirstName() + " " + aCustomerInfo.getLastName() +
                        "\nAddress: " + aCustomerInfo.getStreet() + "\n" + aCustomerInfo.getCity() + "\n" + aCustomerInfo.getState() + "\n" + aCustomerInfo.getZip() +
                        "\n\nTotal Area: " + aCost.getFloorArea() + " square feet" + 
                        "\nCost: " + OutputHelpers.formattedCurrency(aCost.getTotalCost()));

}
}
```

Comment: Why are they static? Do you understand what static variables and methods are for?

Comment: They are static because Eclipse says that they need to be. I didn't have anything set as static until Eclipse said to change them.

Comment: Well, they shouldn't be. Instead, you should avoid trying to access instance variables from static methods, and should avoid making methods static just because you attempted to call them from other static methods. You should simply create an object if you want to access a method or a field.

Comment: To clarify, in another class I am invoking the getTotalCost method, etc. to display the results. Eclipse says that I am making a static reference to a non-static object whenever I don't have the variables set as static.

Comment: So I should create an object in the class that is trying to invoke them? And just to go back to my original question, is the static declaration the reason that I am not seeing any changes in my program when I try to use them?

Comment: It's because you are not actually setting those fields to anything in your private classes. And of course, you should create an object if you are trying to have something that has a state and the state changes. I think you should go back and read a little about fields and static.